# eclipse graphical layout not having black background

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

[image: Im not able to get the black background in the graphical layout]

i downloaded eclipse JUNO and updated with ADT v20 and iam having this problem ...in HELIOS it wrked perfectly before the update  but now this is the problem after the update in HELIOS also.i've tried so many forums but still not able to fix this.thankx in advance guys :)

P.S. this not becuz of the error in xml file and i didnt change background color also(trivial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Add views using Graphical Layout.
Save the file.
Close it.
Reopen it and then make changes to it.
```

or

> change the theme in the layout editor to a default one, such as
>   Holo.light.

Answer (score 0):

go to res-> values-> styles.xml ...and change the Theme.Light to Theme.Black